# What is the difference between Parameter and ParameterTensor?

Tags: cntk

Following the CNTK [docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/BS-Basic-concepts) (revision date 27 Aug 2016), it is mentioned that the way to create parameters is

```
x = ParameterTensor {dim}
```

Also on the [specific docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Parameters-And-Constants#parametertensor) about parameters this is the **only** mentioned way of doing it. Still, in the first docs mentioned and also on the [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TK671HxrufE) by Frank Seide, parameter construction is done with

```
x = Parameter (dim)
```

What is the difference between those two? Is the latter deprecated?

Also, these [docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/BrainScript-Network-Builder) also mention that `Parameter` does not accept a variable number of arguments so it should be used as `Parameter(dim,1)`. I guess this is a breaking change between versions (revision date is Sep 2016 and the talk and examples containing the one argument call are a few months older).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Parameter is deprecated. Use ParameterTensor instead. Sorry about the breaking change too.

Comment: No worries, as long as the docs get updated. If it was a repository I'd PR the changes myself.

Comment: It is a repository! git

Comment: It is a repository! git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK.wiki.git